# Difference between Power Shell cmdlets Copy-Item and Start-Bitstransfer

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, copy-item

Could someone please explain what is the difference between Power Shell "Copy-Item" and "Start-Bitstransfer" cmdlets ?
I'm going to use one of these cmdlets to copy a file from remote share to my local machine. I now that both of them can be run with credentials parameter. I just wanted to know what is the principal difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems I found an explanation. Start-Bitstransfer cmdlet can not be used while making a remote connection.

Comment: It can. In fact it specialises in this type of file transfer.